# Perl Conditional not substituting in scalar value

Tags: perl, if-statement, scalar

For some reason, my if statements aren't working the way I want them to.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $syl;
my $name = "Chris";
print "Enter my name\n";
$syl = <>;
if ($syl eq $name)
{
  print "You entered my name!\n";
}
else
{
  print "That's not my name!\n";
}
```

It looks like it should work from all of the tutorials I've read, but when I type in "Chris" whether capitalized, lowercase, with or without quotation marks, it always evaluates to false. Use Strict and Use Warnings don't tell me I'm doing anything wrong so what, if anything, can I do?

Comment: When debugging this, print the values...`print "That ($syl) is not my name; ($name) is my name!\n";`.  And when you see the unexpected line break in the output, you get a good idea what is wrong.  This is a basic technique in debugging in any language; when something goes wrong, print the erroneous values (and the expected values).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `chomp`.  That strips the newline from the end of the input string that got put there when the user typed 'enter.'

```
$syl = <>;
chomp $syl;
#.... etc...
```